# Application crash using Qualcomm library for IOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios5, opencv, augmented-reality, qcar-sdk

I am using Qualcomm library for my application. My application works fine on iPhone 4S but when I try to install on iPhone 4 then it crashes. The relevant code is:

```
QCAR::Frame frame = state.getFrame();
int frame.getNumImages();
```

with the app crashing on the `getNumImages` line.

I've tested the app on instrument with leaks option and it show me leaks on:

```
NSInteger initSuccess = QCAR::init();
```

with the "Heavies Backtrace" message.

How can I prevent this from crashing?

Comment: what's the entire backtrace and/or error message? this isn't enough info. We might guess that `frame` is NULL so you're dereferencing a NULL pointer. Not sure if the (possible) leak is related to the crash.

Comment: "frame" isn't null, and message is "Thread 12: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,address=0x8)" on line "int num =  frame.getNumImages();" while on installing app on device

Comment: If the address is 0x8, that's still possibly a NULL dereference, but maybe it's internal to the QCAR library. You should update your question with the entire trace.

Comment: Looks like it's a bug in QCAR? https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/excbadaccess-getframe-qcarstate